# how to add two css files one for safari browser and one for ipad desktop version in web page

Tags: javascript, html, css, ipad

I have a web page i want that there should be two css files i web page is opened in safari browser on ipad it should load css one and if it opens direct without browser it should load css two.when you have web page bookmarked it has icon on home screen on ipad so when i click it it open web page without the address bar like safari browser and it shows spaces from botton which does not shows when this online on safari with address bar

```
     <link type="text/css" href="newstyle.css" media="only screen and (min-device-height:674px)and (min-device-width:1024px)  and (orientation:landscape)" rel="stylesheet"  />


      <link type="text/css" href="newstyle_1.css" media="only screen and (min-device-height:748px) and  (min-device-width:1024px)  and (orientation:landscape)" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not merge them altogether for both? Saves you time, effort and HTTP requests. And use a CSS compressor while you are at it too, saving you download time and bandwidth as well.

Comment: listen for browser i use 674 and for desktop i want 768 how may compress this

Comment: in 674 on desktop version it shows blank space from bottom how to fix it any idea

Comment: @user1360291 if you mean resolutions and pages sizes, use [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/Media_queries) to detect the device

Comment: make it clear may i show you screen which shows spaces on desktop without browser

Comment: @user1360291 Can you explain the "without browser" bit to someone who doesn't have an iPad?

Comment: @MrLister when you have web page bookmarked it has icon on home screen on ipad so when i click it it open web page without the address bar like safari browser and it shows spaces from botton which does not shows when this online on safari with address bar

Comment: @user1360291 can you address clarifications by editing your own post?

Comment: @Joseph i have addressed the clarification in my post see my updated post

Answer (score 0):

please use this method based on width, we can solve the issue, we are using this method

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (max-width: 768x)" href="ipad.css" />

<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (max-width: 1024px)" href="desktop.css" />

<link rel="stylesheet"href="comon.css" />
```